# Ограничить количество создаваемых окон Java FX

Tags: javafx

Здравствуйте! На button'е висит хэндлер, который создаёт окно. Как сделать так, чтобы после создания окна нельзя было создать ещё одно посредством нажатия на кнопку?

Сэмпл кода:

```
public void initialize() {
    signUpButtonMainWindowFxml.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        FXMLDocumentController(stage);     
    });
}

private void FXMLDocumentController(Stage stage) {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(REGISTRATION_FORM_FXML_FILE_TITLE));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Stage есть метод isShowing().

```
            if (!stage .isShowing()) {
                String path = "/path.fxml";
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(path));
                Parent root = loader.load();
                stage .setScene(new Scene(root, 640, 480));
                stage .show();
            } else {
                stage .toFront();
            }
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Самый элементарнай способ:

```
private boolean isExists = false;

public void initialize() {
    signUpButtonMainWindowFxml.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
        if ( !isExists ) {
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            FXMLDocumentController(stage);     
            isExists = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Можно удалить `listener` с кнопки после первого создания окна.